# Bootstrap 3.2.0 alert javascript confusion

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts-examples
Under the usage section, it has several js snippets of code. However, merely using markup like

```
<div class="alert alert-warning fade in">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
    a message
</div>
```

results in a fully functioning alert with a fancy fade in on exit. What does that javascript(`$(".alert").alert()`) do? Is it for outdated browsers? Is the documentation outdated?

Comment: When in doubt, [check the source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/js/alert.js)

Comment: It (the plugin) seems to be there to facilitate closing the alert via script, ie `$('.alert').alert('close')`

Comment: @Phil The OP is asking about `.alert()`, not `.alert("close")`. The `.alert("close")` obviously allows you to programmatically close an alert, but what does `.alert()` actually do? The source shows that it listens for **any** `data-dismiss="alert"` in the document, and closes its parent alert. To use `.alert("close")`, you don't need to first run `.alert()`. The docs say that it "Wraps all alerts with close functionality." and "Enable dismissal of an alert via JavaScript", but neither of those make sense...

Comment: @Ian The point is, there could not be an `.alert('close')` without the `.alert()` plugin. The former simply passes a command to the latter. The only other difference is setting up the click event handler on the alert element itself rather than listening at the `document` level.

Comment: @Phil Obviously, you can't call a method with a parameter if the method doesn't exist...so the existence of the `.alert()` method is required in order to call `.alert("close")`...I think we all understand that. What's misleading is the Bootstrap docs, which says calling `.alert()` will "**Enable** dismissal of an alert via JavaScript", which just isn't true. It makes it sound like you **have** to call `.alert()` from JavaScript if you ever want to close it (whether with a `data-dismiss="alert"` attribute or by later calling `.alert("close")`).

Comment: @Phil Including the full Bootstrap library (or simply the Alert plugin), the dismissal of an alert is automatically handled (because the inclusion of the plugin binds a single listener to the `document` for any **click** event from any `data-dismiss="alert"` element on the page at any time). You're absolutely right about the plugin binding a click event to the target element so that the actual removal occurs a lot sooner than at the `document` level. But the click event still propagates to the document and the same removal executes a second time anyways.

Comment: @Phil The only use/benefit I see for specifically calling `.alert()` is to allow the removal happen as soon as possible (well, almost as soon as possible) - since technically other things up the propagation chain could stop the propagation (for example), and therefore the document handler wouldn't see the event and wouldn't remove it. So again, the method needs to be there so that you have the ability to call `.alert("close")`, but this question is specifically about **calling** just `.alert()`

Comment: @Ian, I'm able to do `.alert('close')` without first doing `.alert()`... http://jsfiddle.net/eLUyj/

Comment: @No_name I already said that - "To use `.alert("close")`, you don't need to first run `.alert()`". If I said something that sounded like I contradict that, I didn't mean to. My whole point was this you **don't** need to call `.alert()` for anything else to work. The only thing it seems to provide is a click handler on the `.alert` element. The docs say calling `.alert()` "enables the ability to close", but it doesn't. That's what I thought the confusion was here

Comment: @Ian I agree that some of the Bootstrap docs need work. I've got the `collapse` plugin source code bookmarked due to the number of times I've had to dive in there to find out what it's *actually* doing.

Comment: @Ian "so the existence of the .alert() method is required in order to call .alert("close")" I misread the first time and did not see "existence". Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the difference...

When you enable the `alert` plugin on your `alert` classed element, the plugin registers a *click* event handler on the element, with a delegate target selector of `[data-dismiss="alert"]`.

This is slightly different to the plugin's implicit behaviour (as in, it does this by just including it) of registering a *click* event handler on the `document` itself (same delegate target selector though) in that it moves the event handler closer to the element itself.

The other thing the plugin allows is programmatic closure of the alert by passing in the *"close"* argument, eg `$('.alert').alert('close')`. This still registers a *click* handler as in the first case above and is equivalent to `$('.alert').alert().alert('close')`.

Comment: What then, is the benefit in layman's terms? Performance? Less cluttering of DOM even handlers?

Comment: @No_name I'd say the benefit is flexibility. You may need to stop some click events from reaching the `document` for instance yet still want alerts to close.

Comment: I'm confused why the Api removes the element on close and why wouldn't the Api dynamically create the element on the fly?  There is little value to this since you can't reuse it easily.